# converting datetime from json to readable format

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm getting besides other properties DateTime property which is rendered on the view as

```
/Date(1346997005000)/
```

I should convert this to readable format as dd.mm.yy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dateString = "/Date(1346997005000)/";
var dx = new Date(parseInt(dateString.substr(6)));

var dd = dx.getDate();
var mm = dx.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = dx.getFullYear();

if (dd <= 9) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
}

if (mm <= 9) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
}

var displayDate = dd + "." + mm + "." + yy;
```

Use displayDate. If you have access to one of the numerous JavaScript date libraries (e.g. Moment.js), you should be able to just pass dx into a function and get the display string with one line of code. That'd be a nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is in milliseconds already, so just pass it to the date constructor like this to convert it to a Date object.

```
var d = new Date(unixtimestamp)
```

Then you can use the Date APIs to get parts of the date.

Comment: I think it's already multiplied `> Date(1346997005000)
"Fri Sep 14 2012 04:03:06 GMT-0300 (BRT)"`