# JQuery DataTable and JsonDate, very basic

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419405/converting-datetime-from-json-to-readable-format) very similar to my situation, but I don't know basic steps in integration in JQuery DataTable `DateTime` field. How to insert converted json datetime object into datatable in row like

```
 $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Home/AjaxHandler",

            "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "JoinDate" }
                    ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you search for examples ? http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/ajax.html

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I don't have problem with sending ajax request and retrieve data from controller, only with converting json datetime object and displaying inside code block above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the [fnRender](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) function will help you

```
"aoColumns": [
{
    "sName": "JoinDate",
    "fnRender" : function(obj, val)
    {
        var dx = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
        var dd = dx.getDate();
        var mm = dx.getMonth() + 1;
        var yy = dx.getFullYear();

        if (dd <= 9)
        {
            dd = "0" + dd;
        }
        if (mm <= 9) {
            mm = "0" + mm;
        }
        return dd + "." + mm + "." + yy;
    }
}
]
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, JoinDate should be converted_date, cause I'm currently getting JoinDate as /Date(1346997005000)/

Comment: thanks for the effort, but again simple one, how to use JoinDate as parameter to get var dx = new Date(parseInt(JoinDate.substr(6))); ?

Comment: The column value is passed via the second parameter of the function, so in my example the variable `val` holds the value of `JoinDate`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) solution. All you need is to implement parse function:

```
"columnDefs": [{
                    "render": ParseDateColumn,
                    "targets": 1
                }]

...

function ParseDateColumn(data, type, row) {
    return formatDate(new Date(data), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}
```